# looking for django app for collaborative Wiki

Tags: django, wiki, wiki-engine

I've been trying to find a django wiki app, which has the following -

`1.) WYSIWYG

 2.) Attach files

 3.) Revisions`

I see moinmoin, but before going all in, wanted to see what you all have used.

Comment: is there a reason it has to be django?

Comment: Want to leverage the users already registered. But willing to consider non-django, if it is easy to install and can be configured to use a mysql db for auth.

Comment: Nope.. Also, have stopped looking for now.

Comment: This project addresses the need of a serious wiki for django! https://github.com/benjaoming/django-wiki/

Answer (score 3):

List of Django Wiki projects:
http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/wikis/

Answer (score 1):

The two leading candidates I can find are:

- [django-wikiapp](http://code.google.com/p/django-wikiapp/)
- [django-wiki](https://github.com/sneeu/django-wiki/)

django-wikiapp looks a little more mature, and definitely supports revisions but does not seem to support attachments.  WYSIWYG wouldn't be too tough to implement using something like TinyMCE or CKEditor.  Attachments may be the sticking point.

Answer (score 0):

There is also https://github.com/pinax/django-wakawaka which used in the pinax project. Editing attachments is not supported by the wiki itself but it is suggested to use django-attachments for this use case :)

Comment: We are using https://github.com/pinax/pinax-wiki now when we need a wiki app. You can check out an example usage of this in https://github.com/pinax/pinax-project-wiki.